When I want to install @react-google-maps/api, but I got the error code
When I want to install @react-google-maps/api, but I got an error.
I cannot complete the installation.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-native-formik@1.7.8
npm ERR! Found: formik@2.4.5
npm ERR! node_modules/formik
npm ERR!   formik@"^2.4.5" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer formik@">= 0.11.x < 2" from react-native-formik@1.7.8
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-formik
npm ERR!   react-native-formik@"^1.7.8" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: formik@1.5.8
npm ERR! node_modules/formik
npm ERR!   peer formik@">= 0.11.x < 2" from react-native-formik@1.7.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-formik
npm ERR!     react-native-formik@"^1.7.8" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 

Which version is in conflict? How do to fix it?

tried to delete the react-native-formik in package.json

I got a problem again, I don't know why I cannot upload date to vercel.com
it's show me same error code, but I already deleted react-native-formik
